# Socket reuse not working

Tags: c#, sockets

I have got the following two functions to start and stop a 'local server' (Socket listener).

```
public String startServer(Int32 port, Int32 maximumPendingConnections, ref String errorMsg) {
    try {
        // Creates one SocketPermission object for access restrictions
        permission = new SocketPermission(
        NetworkAccess.Accept,     // Allowed to accept connections 
        TransportType.Tcp,        // Defines transport types 
        "",                       // The IP addresses of local host 
        SocketPermission.AllPorts // Specifies all ports 
        );
        // Listening Socket object 
        sListener = null;
        // Ensures the code to have permission to access a Socket 
        permission.Demand();
        // Resolves a host name to an IPHostEntry instance 
        IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");
        // Gets first IP address associated with a localhost 
        ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
        // Creates a network endpoint 
        ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, port);
        // Create one Socket object to listen the incoming connection 
        sListener = new Socket(
            ipAddr.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream,
            ProtocolType.Tcp
            );
        // Associates a Socket with a local endpoint 
        sListener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true); //newly added as an answer
        sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
        sListener.Listen(maximumPendingConnections);

        // Begins an asynchronous operation to accept an attempt 
        AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);
        sListener.BeginAccept(aCallback, sListener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //ErrorHandling
    }
    return ipAddr.ToString();
}
```

Stop Connection:

```
public void stopServer(ref String errorMsg) {
    try {
        sListener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        sListener.Disconnect(true);
        sListener.Close();
        sListener.Dispose();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Errorhandling
    }
}
```

I have found on SO that you cannot reuse a socket, however if you set `sListener.Disconnect(true);` it should be able to reuse it. Besides I'm creating a new socket every time on starting. What am I missing here?

It gives the error back that every socket can only be used once. It gives an error on `sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);`

@Edit 14:41 - 16-12-2015
I have found that if I add the following line of code before the `sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);` It works;

```
sListener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually to reuse the socket, don't do `Shutdown`, `Close` and `Dispose`, since these calls return the resources used by the socket to the OS. Basically, your socket handler becomes invalid and the work done by `Disconnect(true)` is futile then.

(You also don't need to do `Shutdown` and `Close` at the same time. Just `Close` will do the trick.)

Answer (score 1):

The `Connected` property will always return `false` because socket is in listening state, not connected. Unfortunately, is not possible to "unlisten" the socket so you have to close it and create new socket.

Another issue is: the sequence `Shutdown`, `Disconnect`, `Close` and `Dispose` looks like kicking the dead body.

Comment: Thank you for the additional advice on connected property. I will change that, the sequence is what vovanrock also said. But I guess i just like kicking :-p (also will change that in the question)